# TSP heuristics for limited distance information

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, optimization, tsp, heuristics

this is my first question on Theoretical CS. :)

I've posted a similiar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207012/tsp-heuristics-for-limited-distance-information) on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and a friendly user advised me to post my question on this site.

**Problem:**

> I'm looking for TSP heuristics in the case of limited information about the edges, for example: I have $n$ nodes but can only ask for $~\sim4n$ distances. My graphs are **metric** and
>   I can make an estimate in advance with the euclidean distance, **which provides a lower bound**, but those estimates might be very bad.

**Question:**

> So what are the TSP-Heuristika for those distance-matrices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42756/755), and on MathOverflow and Math.SE.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: BTW there are a few things you should clarify. In my answer I assume that the input is a metric space on $n$ points, i.e. the complete graph with distances that satisfy the triangle inequality. (You can take a metric completion if the graph is not complete.) For the Euclidean estimate you mention: is there any guarantee how bad the estimate is? Is it at least always an overestimate? Or always an underestimate? Otherwise I don't know why you are even bringing it up.

Comment: I've edit my post.

Comment: BTW "my graphs are metrically" is not English and not totally clear. I guess you mean the algorithm has query access to the distances in an $n$ point metric space. Is that the case? Also when you say Euclidean distance, is the dimension constant?

Comment: I've edit my post again. Yes, this is the case. And again yes the dimension is constant.

Comment: @SashoNikolov We have a constant dimension of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no algorithm that runs in time $o(n^2)$ on an $n$-point metric space and returns a tour with weight within a constant factor of the minimum weight: see the argument in Section 9 of this [paper by Indyk](https://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/metrics99.ps).

On the other hand, if you just want an approximation to the *weight* of the optimal tour, without actually getting a tour, then you can use [this algorithm](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos598B/bib/Czumaj-Sohler-EstimMST.pdf) by Czumaj and Sohler. Their algorithm runs in time which is nearly linear in $n/\varepsilon^{O(1)}$ and returns a $1+\varepsilon$ approximation to the weight of minimum weight spanning tree. Since the minimum weight spanning tree is a factor 2 approximation to the minimum weight TSP tour, this gives a factor $2+\varepsilon$ approximation for TSP.

Of course these are worst-case bounds, but I find it implausible to be able to find a good tour by querying $o(n^2)$ edges unless you know more about your metric space. Metric spaces are very general objects and it's easy to hide information while still satisfying the triangle inequality.